# HTACCESS error 500 from dev to live

Tags: .htaccess

I built locally using MAMP a website that I have now put onto a live server. Now each time I goto one of the formatted URL it returns Error 500 but when visiting the links in their original format they work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^api/clients/company/([^/]+)?$ api/clients/company.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/clients/([^/]+)/?$ api/clients/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now when I visit `http://domain.com/api/clients/company/all` it returns Error 500 but when I view `http://domain.com/api/clients/company.php?id=all` the content shows as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` matches everything.
Put your two last rules **before** it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/clients/company/([^/]+)?$ /api/clients/company.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/clients/([^/]+)/?$ /api/clients/index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: YOU SIR! ARE A SAVIOR!

Comment: @Donald You're welcome. Don't forget to validate my answer if it was helpful